# Custom serialize parent and nested items

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a case where I want to remove data from some excess items from the JSON. (I can't just flag the items to not be written with Newtonsoft because I need them for another serialization call.)

I am using the custom serializer to do so, but it doesn't call the serializer for the nested object. Or maybe the SerializeObject that takes an array of JsonConverter isn't the right call.

Here is a full code example, where CSerializer is never called.

```
  public class PItem
  {
    public string name = "Parent";
    public CItem child = new CItem();
    public string type = "P";
  }

  public class CItem
  {
    public string name = "Child";
    public int prop = 100;
    public string[] codes = { "122a", "123b" };
  }

  class PSerializer : JsonConverter
  {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
      PItem p = value as PItem;
      JObject jo = JObject.FromObject((PItem)value);

      jo.Remove("type");    

      jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
      return objectType == typeof(PItem);
    }
  }


  class CSerializer : JsonConverter
  {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
      JObject jo = JObject.FromObject((CItem)value);

      jo.Remove("codes");
      jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
      return objectType == typeof(CItem);
    }
  }



  class JSONTest
  {

    public string TestConvert()
    {
      PItem p = new PItem();
      JsonConverter[] serializers = { new PSerializer(), new CSerializer() };
      return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, serializers);
    }
  }
```

Edit - Working code based on Jesse's solution.

```
class PSerializer : JsonConverter
  {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

      PItem p = value as PItem;
      JObject jo = JObject.FromObject((PItem)value);
      var itemProperties = typeof(PItem).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
                                                        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                                                        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

      var excludeList = new List<string> { "type" };
      var itemProps = jo.Properties().Where(x => itemProperties.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name) && !excludeList.Any(y => y == x.Name));

      writer.WriteStartObject();
      foreach(var itemP in itemProps)
      {        
        writer.WritePropertyName(itemP.Name);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, itemP.Value);
      }

      writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
      return objectType == typeof(PItem);
    }
  }


  class CSerializer : JsonConverter
  {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
      //May cause performance issues but easy to write.
      JObject jo = JObject.FromObject((CItem)value);

      jo.Remove("codes");
      jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
      return objectType == typeof(CItem);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just a sidenote, you don't want to set formatting to indented INSIDE your `JsonConverter`. Set formatting to indented in the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` call instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to do this with a custom `IContractResolver`:

```
public class IgnoreTypeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(PItem) && property.PropertyName == "type")
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = i => false;
            property.Ignored = true;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new IgnoreTypeContractResolver();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pitem, settings);
```

EDIT: If you actually do want to use a `JsonConverter`, you'll have to write the PItem object yourself and serialize the child items using the JsonSerializer:

```
// Inside your custom JsonConverter
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var pitem = value as PItem;
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("name");
    serializer.Serialize(writer, pitem.name);
    writer.WritePropertyName("child");

    // This respects any additional JsonConverters added to the serializer
    serializer.Serialize(writer, pitem.child);
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Comment: I already have the serializer for the parent object and it has to do more than just remove some items, it restructures a bunch of stuff. The nested object just has to remove stuff.  Is there no way to this, what is the array of JsonCovert for?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that, but you'll have to write the properties names of PItem individually in your JsonConverter, using the JsonWriter and then call serializer.Serialize on the values. That way your custom jsonconverter is used on the child item. I tried to avoid that here, because it is quite a drag.

Comment: See my edits to my answer to reflect that latest comment.

Comment: So I kind of liked that solution, but what a pain. Because now I have to explicitly write everything from the child as well because I can't do the jo.WriteTo(writer) because it is in the "WrtieStartObject" mode, and if I end it then I get a whole new object. There should be a way that nested objects auto call their serializer.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why that should not be possible for the child objects. Did you perhaps forget to write the property name first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190318/discussion-between-jesse-de-wit-and-runfastman).